# Linked Selects in angular-js

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

I need to create a two combo box system using the following data:

For the first combo box I managed to populate it using the following:

```
<select ng-model="data.product" ng-options="prod.value as prod.value for 
prod in products"></select>
```

The above shows the list of products.

The second select is proving to be a lot more resilient to my charms and i can't just get to the angular code to do it.

The second one should show the components available for the selected product

The data and structures are bellow:

```
[{
    "map": "product",
    "value": "product 1",
    "components": [{
        "name": "comp 1",
        "local": false
    }]
}, {
    "map": "product",
    "value": "product 2 ",

    "components": [{
        "name": "comp 1",
        "local": false
    }]
}]
```

i now a model with the following structure:

```
{
    "product":"product 1",
    "component":"comp 1"
}
```

Comment: Please provide clarification as to what each select directive is supposed to display/contain.

Comment: Maybe this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zargyle/XV69S/) I put together a while back might help. It sounds like it is similar to what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by defining a function that uses the model value from the first select to return the correct component array. somethink like the following:

```
<select ng-model="data.product" ng-options="prod.value as prod.value for 
prod in products"></select>
<select ng-model="data.component" ng-options="comp.name as comp.name for 
comp in components(data.product)"></select>
```

in my angular code :

```
app.controller('DetailController', function($scope){
    $scope.components = function(value){
        var t =[];
        $scope.products.forEach(function(item){
            if(item.value===value)
                t = item.components;
        });
        return t;
    };
    });
```

This was not really the solution i was looking for, so i will leave this answer unchecked

Answer (score 0):

```
angular.module('app', [])

angular.module('app').controller('sample', ['$scope',
    function($scope) { 
        $scope.products = [{
            "map": "product",
            "value": "product 1",
            "components": [{
                "name": "comp 1",
                "local": false
            }]
        }, {
            "map": "product",
            "value": "product 2 ",

            "components": [{
                "name": "comp 1",
                "local": false
            }]
        }];


    }
])
```

With the Html as

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="sample">
  <select ng-model="product" ng-options="prod.value for prod in products"></select>
  <select ng-model="component" ng-options="comp.name for comp in product.components"></select>
</div>
```